# Is it possible to check hundreds of string arrays by invoking their string names in a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```java
public class MaryPoppinsBagandWeasleyTent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] darkorange = {"3darkchartreuse"};
        String[] stripedfuchsia = {"5stripedlavender"};
        String[] dullgray = {"4mutedcyan", "3lightmaroon"};
        String[] dullchartreuse = {"3lighttan", "3dottedbronze"};
        //etc for hundreds of lines
        String[] names = {"darkorange", "stripedfuchsia",
                "dullgray", "dullchartreuse"}; //etc for hundreds of lines
        String directs = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].contains("shinygold")) {
                System.out.println(names[i]);
                directs += (names[i] + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The list of string arrays, as seen above, is extremely long. I have a corresponding string array of all the names of all the string arrays. Is it possible to call each of these string arrays in the for loop? That’s what I was trying to do with `names[I]`, but that only calls the `STRING names[i]`, not the `String[]` by the name of `names[I]`.

You may hate the extremely long lists of arrays, but I’ll probably learn a better way soon.

Is it possible to check hundreds of string arrays by invoking their string names in a for loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## tl;dr

To better manage such immutable data known at compile-time, create an enum for each color group, with set or list of color names contained within.

```java
enum ColorGroup
{
    DARK_ORANGE( List.of( "3darkchartreuse" ) ),
    DULL_GRAY( List.of( "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" ) );

    private List < String > colors;

    // Constructor
    ColorGroup ( List < String > colors )
    {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    // Getter
    public List < String > getColors ( )
    {
        return this.colors;
    }
}
```

Use that enum.

```java
for ( ColorGroup colorGroup : ColorGroup.values() )
{
    System.out.println( "colorGroup name: " + colorGroup + " contains: " + colorGroup.getColors() );
}
```

> colorGroup name: DARK_ORANGE contains: [3darkchartreuse]
>
> colorGroup name: DULL_GRAY contains: [4mutedcyan, 3lightmaroon]

---

## `Map`

If you want to associate a textual name to each array, use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). A map stores entries as a pairing, a key that leads to a value. In your case, the key would be a `String` object and the value would be an array.

```java
Map < String, String[] > map = new TreeMap <>();
map.put( "Dark Orange" , new String[] { "3darkchartreuse" } );
map.put( "Dull Gray" , new String[] { "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" } );

System.out.println( map );
```

When run:

> {Dark Orange=[Ljava.lang.String;@77459877, Dull Gray=[Ljava.lang.String;@5b2133b1}

### Enum versus text

Using text for such labeling can be error-prone. For example, spelling `"Dark Grey"` versus `"Dark Gray"`.

So you may choose to use the very simple but powerful [enum facility found in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#Java). Enum objects are [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)), automatically instantiated when their class loads. As constants, their names are written in all-uppercase per Java conventions. As named objects, their use detects spelling errors at compile-time, and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) too.

```java
enum ColorGroupName
{
    DARK_ORANGE,
    DULL_GRAY
}
```

#### `EnumMap`

For a `Map` using enum objects as keys, use the [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) implementation for very fast execution using very little memory.

```java
Map < ColorGroupName, String[] > map = new EnumMap( ColorGroupName.class );
map.put( ColorGroupName.DARK_ORANGE , new String[] { "3darkchartreuse" } );
map.put( ColorGroupName.DULL_GRAY , new String[] { "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" } );

System.out.println( map );
```

### Collection versus array

Many of us prefer [collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) over arrays.

```java
Map < ColorGroupName, List < String > > map = new EnumMap( ColorGroupName.class );
map.put( ColorGroupName.DARK_ORANGE , List.of( "3darkchartreuse" ) );
map.put( ColorGroupName.DULL_GRAY , List.of( "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" ) );

System.out.println( map );
```

When run:

> {DARK_ORANGE=[3darkchartreuse], DULL_GRAY=[4mutedcyan, 3lightmaroon]}

#### Immutable data

If your map is meant to be unchanging, use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V)) to create an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable).

```java
Map < ColorGroupName, List < String > > map =
        Map.of(
                ColorGroupName.DARK_ORANGE , List.of( "3darkchartreuse" ) ,
                ColorGroupName.DULL_GRAY , List.of( "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" )
        );

System.out.println( map );
```

## Enum containing data

If you want to be quite clever, you can store your list of colors within your enum.

An enum is a special kind of Java class, but still a Java class. As a Java class it can carry member variables. And it can offer a constructor. To store data within the enum, pass the data for each enum object to its constructor call.

```java
enum ColorGroup
{
    DARK_ORANGE( List.of( "3darkchartreuse" ) ),
    DULL_GRAY( List.of( "4mutedcyan" , "3lightmaroon" ) );

    private List < String > colors;

    // Constructor
    ColorGroup ( List < String > colors )
    {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    // Getter
    public List < String > getColors ( )
    {
        return this.colors;
    }
}
```

Use that enum.

```java
for ( ColorGroup colorGroup : ColorGroup.values() )
{
    System.out.println( "colorGroup name: " + colorGroup + " contains: " + colorGroup.getColors() );
}
```

> colorGroup name: DARK_ORANGE contains: [3darkchartreuse]
>
> colorGroup name: DULL_GRAY contains: [4mutedcyan, 3lightmaroon]

## `Map` implementations

Here is a chart I made to help with choosing a `Map` implementation.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for providing way more context. The other answer looks more like a copy/paste one.

Comment: @pzaenger Your comment prompted me to put my final best solution up top in a new “tl;dr” section. Thanks.

Comment: @BasilBourque Your solution is in fact the authoritative one. It has been re-accepted. True, the answer was long, but your thoroughness is appreciated. The other post received acceptance to help increase TheStackWizards' reputation.

Comment: Hopefully @TheStackWizards will delete the plagiaristic post.

Comment: Your answer deserves the bounty, but another user may get it, in order to increase the reputation and participation of new users.                                                                                    
                 If you would like, you will receive the bounty when it becomes due.  
                                                                                                                        
                However, if you would like to be generous, as you were with your knowledge, would you consider allowing another similarly thorough answer to receive the award?

Comment: @StackOverFlowerProgrammer Thanks for asking, but I have more than enough points. I’ll never catch up to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) anyways.  :-)

Comment: @BasilBourque this is just an excellent answer. Congrats for this

Comment: `EnumMap` is not only about clever - it is more lightweight and faster.

Answer (score 0):

store keys and values in one array of delimiter-separated strings (easier to maintain), e.g.

```
public class MaryPoppinsBagandWeasleyTent {

    private static final String DELIMITER_SEMICOLON = ";";

    private static final String[] OPTIONS = {
            "darkorange;3darkchartreuse",
            "stripedfuchsia;5stripedlavender",
            "dullgray;4mutedcyan;3lightmaroon",
            "dullchartreuse;3lighttan;3dottedbronze",

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String q = "dullgray";
        String[] split;
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(0);
        for (String o : OPTIONS) {
            if (null != o && o.startsWith(q)) {
                split = o.split(DELIMITER_SEMICOLON);
                for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
                    result.add(split[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using 2D array for storing your String arrays. You can use the code below for this implementation.

```
String[] names = {"darkorange", "stripedfuchsia",
            "dullgray", "dullchartreuse"};

    String directs = "";

    String[][] matrix = {darkorange, stripedfuchsia,
            dullgray, dullchartreuse}; // 2D string arrays

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j= 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        if (matrix[i][j]=="shinygold") {
            System.out.println(names[i]);
            directs += (names[i] + ",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```java
Map<String, String[]> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("Dark Orange", new String[]{"3darkchartreuse"});
map.put("Dull Gray", new String[]{"4mutedcyan", "3lightmaroon"});

System.out.println(map);
```